# Is a way to see the errors of a site on android mobile without installing any app?

Tags: android, html, github, mobile-chrome, samsung-browser

I use github to code html sites and to host it but I do not find a way to see the errors of my site on mobile.

Is a way to see the errors of a site on chrome or samsung browser on android mobile or does anyone know a site where you can see the errors of another site (not only of the html file for all imported files) ?

Comment: Since you could be using any browser and there's no requirement that Android ship with a particular one, that's really unanswerable.  Your browser may have a developer mode, it may not.

Comment: Using BrowserStack Automate, or your Chrome browser's Developer Tools, this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use each browser's developer mode to show the mobile version of a website. Check out the documentations e.g. for [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/), [Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/responsive_design_mode/) and [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-developer-tools/responsive-design-mode).
2. You can use mobile device farms to remotely connect to a smartphone and control it. There are paid services for this like [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/). Samsung also offers remote connections to its devices for free in their [remote test lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab).
3. You can install an android emulator and download various browsers. The easiest approach is to download and install Android Studio and set up the [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) there. For iOS you require a Mac and Xcode.
4. You can use tools like Google's [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/) to check your website for errors. Additionally, if you set up [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) for your website, you'll get automatic reports if your site contains obvious problems. It can find problems on mobile websites when the text is too small or if buttons are too close together.
   [image: Example errors for mobile website usability from Google Search Console]